# MapVirtualKeyExA with different keyboard layouts

Tags: c++, winapi, keylogger

I try to use `MapVirtualKeyExA` with different keyboard layouts. This function always returns English letters, no matter what keyboardlayout parameter I pass.

[image]

I use console app and get layout by `GetKeyboardLayout`:

```
 HWND foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
 DWORD threadId;
 HKL keyboardLayout;
 if (foreground) 
 {
    threadId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foreground, NULL);
    keyboardLayout = GetKeyboardLayout(threadId); 
 }
```

Convert `keyCode` to `char` :

```
char crrKey;
bool lower = ((GetKeyState(VK_CAPITAL) & 0x0001) != 0);
if ((GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x1000) != 0 || (GetKeyState(VK_LSHIFT) & 0x1000) != 0 || (GetKeyState(VK_RSHIFT) & 0x1000) != 0) 
{
    lower = !lower;
}
crrKey = MapVirtualKeyExA(key, MAPVK_VK_TO_CHAR, keyboardLayout);
cout << keyboardLayout << ": " << crrKey << endl;
if (!lower) 
{
    crrKey = tolower(crrKey);
}
file << char(crrKey);
```

I want that when changing the language **(Windows + Space) VirtualKey** is mapped to the new language. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try reading: `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Input\Locales` to find the default locale

Comment: In registry `Name: Default, Type: REG_SZ, Value: (Empty)`. Update question, plese chek.

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using the ANSI version (`MapVirtualKeyExA`) as opposed to the Unicode version (`MapVirtualKeyExW`)?

Comment: At first i use MapVirtualKeyExW and get the same result. Not a particular.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could use [ToUnicodeEx API](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-tounicodeex?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to translate the specified virtual-key code and keyboard state to the corresponding Unicode character or characters.